# Upload multiple images, before display

Tags: jquery, html, image, upload

I want upload multiple images, i use this for show image, but works only for one:

```
function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
```

and html

```
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" multiple>
<img id="uploadPreview" style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

i want upload images, but before upload i want show all.
And how i can get image name without extension from image "preview"?

thanks :) and please help, best regards!

Comment: .files[0] = the first file. I see no code for handling additional files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way of uploading multiple files :-
I am not sure if i have understood your question. Please let me know if i have not understood it perfectly.

```
var input = document.getElementById('inputname');
var list = document.getElementById('fileList');

while (list.hasChildNodes()) {
    list.removeChild(ul.firstChild);
}

for (var x = 0; x < input.files.length; x++) {

    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = 'File ' + (x + 1) + ':  ' + input.files[x].name;
    list.append(li);
}
```